# How to move file from one folder to another folder same ftp using python

Tags: python, ftp

How move files from one folder to another folder in same ftp using python 
i used this code but it doesn't work out

```
ftp=FTP("host")
ftp.login("user name","password")
def downloadFiles(path,destination):
    try:
        ftp.cwd(path)
         #clone path to destination
        ftp.dir(destination)
        #~ os.mkdir(destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path)
        print destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path+" built"
    except OSError:
        #folder already exists at destination
        pass
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        #invalid entry (ensure input form: "/dir/folder/something/")
         print "error: could not change to "+path
         sys.exit("ending session")

    filelist=ftp.nlst()

    for file in filelist:
         try:
             #this will check if file is folder:
             ftp.cwd(path+file+"/")
             #if so, explore it:
             downloadFiles(path+file+"/",destination)

         except ftplib.error_perm:
             #not a folder with accessible content
             #download & return
             #~ os.chdir(destination[0:len(destination)]+path)
             #possibly need a permission exception catch:
             #~ ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+ file, open(ftp.path.join(destination,file),"wb").write)
             ftp.storlines("STOR "+file, open(ftp.dir(destination, file),'r')) 
             print file + " downloaded"
    return
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! State precisely: a) What you are tried so far (show a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**) b) Where are you getting stuck (again show code).

Comment: try `ftplib`  module and `rename()` function.

Comment: @steven Barnes See question below  i used that  code

Comment: @Arunagirik - the formatting of the code in your question did not include formatting the first 3 lines __as code__.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the excellent python file system abstraction [pyfs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fs) as you can see from the [documents](http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/interface.html) all of the file systems, once mounted, have `copy`, `copydir`, `move` and `movedir` methods, *personally I would always copy, verify then delete for safety especially on a remote system.*

Comment: i downloaded ftp file in local system its working fine but its not worked in same ftp folder

Comment: The first question of course is does your account have __write__ access to both the server and the directory.

Answer (score 0):

In python, move files from one folder to another one, move(current path, target path).

```
from shutil import move
move(current path, target path)
```

It could happen when this function not working since it takes time based on the file size. Good practice is that stop for a while before the function.

```
import time
from shutil import move
time.sleep(3)
move(current path, target path)
```

Comment: I think I should raise a question on how to break lines in the code -_-

Comment: The question is explicitly about moving files on an FTP server through FTP, which you don't answer at all. Also, losing 3 seconds in a `sleep` before moving files is not good practice at all, on the contrary.